# Oracle 11g Trigger Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I'm a newbie to database and trying to create a trigger which will change a char from "Y" to "N" if another table's tuple is set to 0. I have it working somewhat but it is changing all tuples instead of the single one I want. Here is the trigger and code. Any suggestions gratefully received.

```
create or replace TRIGGER CHANGE_STOCK_FLAG
AFTER UPDATE OF AMOUNT_REMAINING ON PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE BOOK

SET IN_STOCK = 'N';

END;
```

Update statement:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT
SET AMOUNT_REMAINING = 0
WHERE PROD_ID = 5001;
```

The trigger compiled OK and on update above resets IN_STOCK to "N" on all tuples in the Book TABLE.
Is there a where clause or something I can use?

Comment: Can you share the DDLs to your `book` and `product` tables please?

Comment: Thanks for tidying it up Eat A Peach. It messed up when posted. Any Suggestions?

Comment: How your PRODUCT and BOOK tables are connected? How to define for which book to change the value of IN_STOCK column?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, Heres the Tables    CREATE TABLE PRODUCT 
(
  PROD_ID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, AMOUNT_REMAINING NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, PRICE NUMBER(9, 2) NOT NULL 
, IN_STOCK CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PK PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Sorry Mureinik, Heres the other one  CREATE TABLE BOOK 
(
  BOOK_ID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, ISBN_ID VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, TITLE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, PROD_ID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, IN_STOCK CHAR(1 BYTE) 
, CONSTRAINT BOOK_PK PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    BOOK_ID 
  )

Comment: Techically, whether something is in stock or not is derived information - if you have more that `0` items on hand, it's in stock.  How many rows are there in your table - would it be reasonable to derive this at query-time?  If you don't want to have to remember it all the time, it could be included in a view (which could be persisted/cached if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_STOCK_FLAG 
AFTER UPDATE OF AMOUNT_REMAINING ON PRODUCT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (:NEW.AMOUNT_REMAINING=0) THEN
  UPDATE BOOK SET IN_STOCK = 'N' WHERE PROD_ID=:NEW.PROD_ID;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Guneli, That worked. I'll need to look up the code changes you made re: referencing and if statement to understand this. Thanks again.

Comment: You should probably have it check for _negative_ stock, too (so, `NEW.AMOUNT_REMAINING <= 0`).  Afterall, there's such a thing as shrink in a retail environment.